# Export to static site functionality (flask application)

Tags: python, html, css, flask, static

I am working on a flask application. I am quite new in the web development area and was wondering if it is possible to create some functionality that can export a current view to a static website with all css inlined in the exported html as well (or to PDF even).

Comment: Is in-lining CSS a hard requirement? There is [Frozen Flask](https://github.com/Frozen-Flask/Frozen-Flask) which exports your flask app to static files. Although, as far as I know it won't inline your CSS for you, but I believe there are other projects that could take the static export from Frozen Flask and produce the equivalent with inlined CSS. One such project is [inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css)

Comment: that looks very promising. I will give it a try as soon as time allows